# Can't track remote branch - doesn't recognize origin/develop

Tags: git

I have git 1.8.3 and a repo with 'master' and 'develop' branches.

From my local 'develop' branch, I'm trying to do the following command -

`git branch -u origin/develop`

and I get an error of

`error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/develop' does not exist`

When I check `git branch -r` I see only `origin/master`

I'm trying to find a way to make my system recognize that there is also a `origin/develop` and can't find any solution that works.

Comment: Did you try to run `git fetch origin`? It should fetch all branches from the remote, not just master.

Comment: Yes... maybe there is something wrong with my repo, I tried that several times

Comment: If you cloned the repository with `--depth` or `--single-branch` it will  track just the one branch by default.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- If the branch `develop` already exists in the remote repository, use `git fetch` to update your "remote-tracking branches" (local mirrors).

  - This requires that the fetch refspec is set correctly (in `.git/config` in the section for your remote); the default is `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<name of remote>/*`. In some cases, configuration may be set up to fetch only one branch (specific branch name used instead of wildcard). It should be safe to change the configuration; this will allow fetching all branches.
- If the branch doesn't exist yet in the remote repository, you can set up the association while pushing it for the first time: `git push -u origin develop` (that takes care of what you're trying to do with your command at the same time as it pushes the branch)

Comment: Thanks Jan, but when I write `git fetch origin` it doesn't show the develop in the remote... that's why it's so confusing...

Comment: It doesn't show when you do `git branch -r` locally after fetching? In that case, the branch doesn't exist in the remote repository; that case is covered by the second bullet point.

Comment: THanks Jan, When I do `git push origin develop` it works, and when I do `git pull origin develop` it also works, and also I see it on github (private repo).. so it's there, but just not showing locally for some reason

Comment: Maybe your refspecs are weird... look at the section `[remote "origin"]` in .git/config. It should have this line: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` – if the `fetch` line is different (or even missing), fetch may not be properly updating everything in the `origin/` namespace.

Comment: You're right! it was set as - +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master and not with *, please update your answer and I'll accept it, thanks Jan!

Comment: But what the local branch is already tracking a remote branch, but I want to switch tracking to a branch that doesn't exist. When I do that then I get get an error message error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/the_uncreated_branch' does not exist. I have tried git pushing with -u set but that doesn't change it from the old existing remote to the new uncreated remote.

Comment: I found this `git branch --unset-upstream` here (http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/understanding-tracking-branches-in-git) which let me remote the upstream and let me push to the new remote.

Comment: i faced a similar issue at my workplace. and found out later that the 'branch' had been protected and restricted to push by developer role. So that was accordingly addressed; followed by $git remote add origin <remote-url>